# Image module cannot be found even though the path is correct

Tags: javascript, react-native

Even though the path for my image is correct, I keep getting the error "unable to resolve module './assets/logo.png' the module './assets/logo.png' cannot be found. Indeed none of these files exist: logo.png

```
import React, { Component, Path } from "react";


import styles from "./style";
import {Keyboard, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Alert, KeyboardAvoidingView, Image, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';


export default class LoginScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
  <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.containerView} behavior="padding">

  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
    <View style={styles.loginScreenContainer}>
      <View style={styles.loginFormView}>

      <Image source={require('./repos/login-screen/assets/logo.png')}/>

      <Text style={styles.logoText}>LootBox</Text>
      <Text style={styles.logoText}>Create an Account</Text>
        <TextInput placeholder="Username" placeholderColor="#c4c3cb" style={styles.loginFormTextInput} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Password" placeholderColor="#c4c3cb" style={styles.loginFormTextInput} secureTextEntry={true}/>
        <Button
          buttonStyle={styles.loginButton}
          onPress={() => this.onLoginPress()}
          title="Create Account"
        />
```

The line that is causing it is the `<image source>` line. Am I formatting it wrong?

Comment: Your error message does not match your code at all

Comment: you need to restart the bundler when you add new assets.